# A word to describe Yes, No and unknown

Tags: single-word-requests, yes-no

I am facing a problem during programming.
I am trying to describe a collection of three words.
Is there a word for **yes**, **no** and **unknown** ?

The words for example could describe if someone is authorized to do something, so I could call the collection *Authorization*. I could describe if someone is certain, so I could call it *certainty*. My question is, is there a "meta" word for that ?

You could for example say light blue, royal blue, airforce blue and sky blue are words to describe blue but the "meta" word for that would be colour.

The context in which I am trying to use that word is, as stated above, a programming scenario

```
public enum MISSINGWORD
{
    unknown = 0,
    Yes = 1,
    No = 2,
}
```

I don't have a real live example, where you would need that word other then describing the abstract collection of those three words without any adjective  tied to it.

Comment: You could say you're implementing [Three-state logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic) using a ***tri-state flag***.

Comment: Of interest:  http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_

Comment: @FumbleFingers - in understanding the *state* of circuits, 'unknown' is X, not the z which corresponds to the high impedance state of tri-state circuits.  I do think this question refers to *state*, regardless.  In logic design, we'd refer to the state of a latch being 1, 0, or-- given a powerup sequence which cannot guarantee either state-- X, meaning unknown.  A set or reset forces the state to a known value.

Comment: @stevesliva: I don't do electrical circuits, but I wrote program code for decades, in which context I made extensive use of "tri-state flags" - integers where 0/1 had the usual sense *False/True, No/Yes,* with -1 being reserved for *Not yet set, Unknown*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - you linked to an article about logic *circuits*.  For those circuits, specifically, the 3rd state is Z.  Not an unknown state, but Z.  In verilog HDL, the Z state (high-impedance) is a different state than the X state (unknown).   I'm aware of programming constructs like optionals (specifically optional bools) in Swift that support true/false/unknown.  It's just that, being a circuit guy as well as a programming guy, I can't see a list of "true/false/unknown" likened to tri-state *logic*-- this is a specific, physical type of circuit, not just a term-- and not quibble.

Comment: @stevesliva: oic. I never actually went to that Wikipedia page - I just googled "tri-state flag" and grabbed the text *Three-state logic* and URL straight from the results page. (My usage obviously isn't particularly "standard", in that I had to skip a page or two of results dominated by some outfit that apparently sells flags/pennants in at least 3 US states! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are *Ternary* values (AKA *trivalent* values). A variable holding such value is sometimes called a [Trilean](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/util/Trilean.html).

Instead of using [Bivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence) variables and some Bivalent logical system (Boolean logic is the most common), you are using Trivalent variables. Several [ternary logical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) (e.g. Kleene, Priest and Łukasiewicz) are defined with Trivalent variables .

Answer (score 0):

I would go for (degree of) **Certainty** as in:

cer•tain•ty /ˈsɝtənti/ the state of being certain
[uncountable]

Or even better: **Trueness**